# Support to get the features implemented in a single query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is there a way to optimize the following to a single query?

```
$username=sanitize($_POST['username']);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' AND email='$email' AND amount='$donation_amount'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num_rows==1){
$sql1="UPDATE $tbl_name SET password='$new_password' WHERE username='$username' AND email='$email' AND amount='$donation_amount'";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
$num_rows1=mysql_affected_rows();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may please omit the `SELECT` and `$num_rows` part.

The `UPDATE` clause suffices: record(s) found according to your predicate (i.e., `WHERE` condition) will be updated as specified in the SET clause; if no records are found, the table/relvar will be "as is" (i.e., no update will take place.)

Hope it helps.

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood the question in the first place. Your answer is the one :)

Comment: Thank you for your understanding.. its okay.. same happened to me before :)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to check whether the username / email / amount exist in the system.  Just use $num_rows1 to detect whether you updated a record in the database - this will tell you whether there was a match or not.

However, if Username, Email, and Amount are not enough to ensure a unique record (i.e. there is the possibility that you will match more than one record on the database), then this will not work. In that case, what I would recommend is finding a set of fields that, together, represent a unique key, and ensuring you're checking those as part of the update.